# Configure Spring Integration SpEl in java config

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-el

I'm using spring integration to call another service via http. I'm using annotations for configuring spring integration, but I have a problem when I want my service url be configurable based on message payload. Current code looks like this:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myChannel")
public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler otherServiceHttpCall() {
    final HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpHandler =
            new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://localhost:8080/updateStatus/{id}?");
    httpHandler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    httpHandler.setOutputChannel(posPaymentResponse());
    return httpHandler;
}
```

I know I can add an expression by calling `httpHandler.setUriVariablesExpression` or `httpHandler.setUriVariableExpressions`, but I don't know how to create SpEl expressions programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the code like we in the Framework:

```
private final static SpelExpressionParser PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();
```

And use that `PARSER` to populate `Expression` from `String`

```
PARSER.parseExpression("headers.url");
```